# Eclipse/Java - deactivate temporarily save action "functional interface instances"

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse IDE programming in Java and usually I don't have any problems with the save action "Functional interface instances: simplify lambda expression and method reference syntax".

However, in this case it changes `.map(t -> ensureClosedPeriods(t))` to
`.map(this::ensureClosedPeriods)`.

This causes a problem, as the method is static:
**Cannot use this in a static context**.

I really like this save action, but I don't want this to apply to this part of the code.

`@formatter:off` does not work in this case.

Does anyone know any solution?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like a bug in the action that is refactoring your code. In terms of "any solution", presumably you could rewrite it like this:

```
.map(classname::ensureClosedPeriods)
```

where `classname` is the name of the class that defines the static method.

Comment: And then report it as a bug to bugs.eclipse.org.

Comment: @nitind: I'll do it. :)